# c# selenium how to findelements to style range?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver

Examples of styles I have:

```
    <map name="workmap">
  <area shape="rect" style="left:88 ;top:131;" alt="Computer" onclick="javascript: SelectSeat('SNO01', '1')">
  <area shape="rect" style="left:89 ;top:135;" alt="Monitor" onclick="javascript: SelectSeat('PEK23', '1')">
  <area shape="circle" style="left:90 ;top:138;" alt="Printer" onclick="javascript: SelectSeat('GGE13', '1')">
</map>
```

I'm about to click imagemap.
The only element provided is style. I want to scan all the elements that fall within the style range.

```
driver1.FindElements(By.XPath(@"//*
[contains(@style,'top:<200') and 
contains(@style,'top:>100') and 
contains(@class,'minimap')]"));
```

An error occurred when I followed the code above, so I'm asking for help...

and

Can I find the element in the C# selenium location value range?

Comment: please edit your question and insert a description of the error that occurs. Maybe you can try to make the question a bit clearer as well.

Comment: @mandang - Show us the error that you get.

Comment: @ruud Modified code sample.
What I want to do is find the <Area> value within a specific scope of the browser.
I wonder if the method I explained can be implemented in selenium.

ex) i wnat to find elements <style> top >=100 and top <= 136

Comment: @TalAngel I modified the code.

Comment: Please include more of the HTML in the web page. You frequently can use ancestor elements on the page to make a CSS selector or XPath expression unique enough to identify the elements without resorting to complex calculations.